# Find size of modules before repo sync starts

Tags: android, git

Need help on how to find out the size of modules before 'repo sync' starts. The size of repositories have inflated so much that one does not know what lies ahead after starting the sync. I am finding individual modules with sizes of about 1GB or even more and total repo ranges to 6-8GB specially with Android repositories and all are not required to be downloaded. After knowing the sizes I can decide which is required and which are not and accordingly edit the default.xml.

I did the inital hoemwork of finding out on web, but was not successful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: which repo r u using?

Comment: https://android.googlesource.com/, if this is what you meant

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure in your case, but during "**Repo sync**", if we run with '**--depth 0**', it will download/clone the latest revision. Normally in repo file you will get an option to add the same. I hope it will help you :)